# Sprites is not loading in Ad-HOC mode in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, cocos2d-x, ad-hoc-distribution

I am completely stumped here. Created my game, all working in XCode' simulator and also on my device when directly deployed from XCode.

I Submitted my app and they rejected it and asked me to run in Ad-HOC mode in my device to test since the app was not working.

I can replicate the issue in Ad-HOC mode.

> Issue: Once replace scene is invoked, the tile map is not populating
>   the Sprites from the sprite-sheet created using the TexturePacker
>   software. The app does not crash, however the Scene is empty with just
>   the background without any Sprites loaded in it.

Not sure how can this be a code issue since works fine when I install directly from XCode.

Please help, thanks in advance :)

Comment: try running the release config of the scheme to see if this is perhaps a release build issue, ie an #ifdef DEBUG or overly aggressive compiler optimizations

Comment: Thanks, I am almost certain than I have not used #ifdef DEBUG in the code. How can I tell that its overly aggressive compiler optimizations?
Also, I have exported the sprite-sheet in .png format, I hope that is not the issue.

Comment: change compiler optimizations to none for release config under target's build settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@LearnCocos2D, Thanks, I found out the bug last night. I did not use CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() when placing sprites using tilemap co-ordinates. Amazing thing is, it worked in debug mode but did not as soon as I released the binary :)